# KivyMD onkeypress event - Python

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

Hi I am trying to achieve an onkey press event for an application that i am building using kivymd. I am using Kivy to deploy my python application as an android app. Somehow I have a use case where when some text is written and it matches a string i want to do some functionality on the fly. So i wanted to track onkeypress event. I tried below but i am not sure its write way. The _on_keyboard_down works if I use a Widget instead of MDApp. I just wanted to know if there was a way to make it work in Kivy MDApp. A simple onkeypress .

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
import helpers
from kivy.core.window import Window

class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, self)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green"
        screen = Screen()
        self.img = Image(source='img.jpeg',
                           size_hint=(0.5, 0.5),
                           pos_hint={'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .8})
        self.item = Builder.load_string(helpers.item_input)
        self.cost = Builder.load_string(helpers.cost_input)
        screen.add_widget(self.img)
        screen.add_widget(self.item)
        screen.add_widget(self.cost)
        return screen

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard = None

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        if keycode[1] == 'w':
            print("w Pressed")
        elif keycode[1] == 's':
            print("s Pressed")
        return True

MyApp().run()
```